# Design options for turning on charger. Would this work?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design

I intend to use [this charger.](https://www.meanwellusa.com/productPdf.aspx?i=28)

To turn it on you would open the contacts RC- and RC+. For certain reasons, I can't use a NC switch.

I only have access to VBAT (40-56 V) and a NO switch. Could you suggest ways I could design a circuit that would meet these requirements?

Edit: I think it wasn't clear initially but I need to use a NO limit switch. So options like SPDT or other NO switches won't be an option.

Would something like the following work?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the signal used to turn it on in your application? Can you just bridge RC- and RC+ with a wire and let it run?

Comment: @winny The signal is the switch being closed. Once a NO switch is closed, i'd like the RC- and RC+ to become 'open' and that would activate the charger.

Comment: Sure, but what drives the relay? Can you hook into that signal?

Comment: Could you use a NO switch and just relabel which position is on and which position is off, thereby turning it into a NC switch? By the way, how much current does your relay need in order to operate? If it needs more than 2.8 mA, then that resistor will prevent it from working. You might need a much smaller resistor, like 100 ohms or something.

Comment: @winny What drives the relay? Do you mean the coil? The regulated zener voltage once the switch is closed.

Comment: @Tanner-reinstateLGBTpeople thats a fair point you're right. I will adjust the resistor match whatever coil current is necessary. 
The switch i have is a NO limit switch so there are just 2 contacts. Are you thinking of a spdt?

Comment: No, your NO switch. Is it manual

Comment: Change your NO switch to DPDT and switch on the power supply with the other pole.

Comment: @Hasman404 Ah, I didn't realize it was a limit switch. I was guessing that it was a toggle switch or something, where you could effectively turn it into a NC switch by turning it upside down.

Answer (score 0):

A 48 V DC automotive relay is to be used.

Here's the schematic.

[image]

Comment: I have added an edit, it was probably not clear but i am limited to use a NO limit switch. So this wont' do.

Comment: Hi Hasman404, My answer has been duly edited.